# How to create a JSONObject from String in Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin

I need to convert a string `{\"name\":\"test name\", \"age\":25}` to a JSONObject

Comment: This URL might be a good starting point for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin

Comment: Depends on which *kind* of JSONObject, for org.json see https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/

Comment: And what backend? Java or JS?

Answer (score 66):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question but it sounds like you are already using org.json which begs the question about why

```
val answer = JSONObject("""{"name":"test name", "age":25}""")
```

wouldn't be the best way to do it? What was wrong with the built in functionality of JSONObject?

Comment: Did you test your example using Kotlin? If yes, what version of the library did you use? If you try that with JSONObject version `org.json:json:20200518` you'll see that the contructor with a String object is not available in the JSONObject.

Comment: Yes actually and given that the answer was provided back in 2017 I'm sure there have been quite a number of changes that have taken place over the past 3 years. However, the link to which json version is in the original post's comment. Here is a direct link to the javadoc https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: I just pulled up the 20200518 version of the source code and see that it does still support the string constructor just fine. Line 405 on https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/8e5b516f2bab9b81098ef57a7e84076c28441428/JSONObject.java

Answer (score 48):

```
val rootObject= JSONObject()
rootObject.put("name","test name")
rootObject.put("age","25")
```

Comment: This answer assumes you already know the fields and values, which the asker can't know if they haven't parsed the string yet.

Comment: How did this answer get so many upvotes!? It does not answer the question. The input data should be a JSON string, this example shows how to build a new JSONObject field by field.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the OP's question, but this did help me understand how to easily create JSON out of my data objects without adding another lib to my project.

Answer (score 18):

You can use https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon library.

```
val parser: Parser = Parser()
val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder("{\"name\":\"Cedric Beust\", \"age\":23}")
val json: JsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
println("Name : ${json.string("name")}, Age : ${json.int("age")}")
```

Result :

```
Name : Cedric Beust, Age : 23
```

Comment: This way is more preferable if you going to use this object as a result of API method since `JsonObject` from **klaxon** knows how to serialize itself back to Json.

Comment: `Parser()` is deprecated, use `Parser.default()` instead

Answer (score 4):

The approaches above are a bit dangerous: They don't provide a solution for illegal chars. They don't do the *escaping*... And we hate to do the escaping ourselves, don't we?

So here's what I did. Not that cute and clean but you have to do it only once.

```
class JsonBuilder() {
    private var json = JSONObject()

    constructor(vararg pairs: Pair<String, *>) : this() {
        add(*pairs)
    }

    fun add(vararg pairs: Pair<String, *>) {
        for ((key, value) in pairs) {
            when (value) {
                is Boolean -> json.put(key, value)
                is Number -> add(key, value)
                is String -> json.put(key, value)
                is JsonBuilder -> json.put(key, value.json)
                is Array<*> -> add(key, value)
                is JSONObject -> json.put(key, value)
                is JSONArray -> json.put(key, value)
                else -> json.put(key, null) // Or whatever, on illegal input
            }
        }
    }

    fun add(key: String, value: Number): JsonBuilder {
        when (value) {
            is Int -> json.put(key, value)
            is Long -> json.put(key, value)
            is Float -> json.put(key, value)
            is Double -> json.put(key, value)
            else -> {} // Do what you do on error
        }

        return this
    }

    fun <T> add(key: String, items: Array<T>): JsonBuilder {
        val jsonArray = JSONArray()
        items.forEach {
            when (it) {
                is String,is Long,is Int, is Boolean -> jsonArray.put(it)
                is JsonBuilder -> jsonArray.put(it.json)
                else -> try {jsonArray.put(it)} catch (ignored:Exception) {/*handle the error*/}
            }
        }

        json.put(key, jsonArray)

        return this
    }

    override fun toString() = json.toString()
}
```

Sorry, might have had to cut off types that were unique to my code so I might have broken some stuff - but the idea should be clear

You might be aware that in Kotlin, "to" is an infix method that converts two objects to a Pair. So you use it simply like this:

```
   JsonBuilder(
      "name" to "Amy Winehouse",
      "age" to 27
   ).toString()
```

But you can do cuter things:

```
JsonBuilder(
    "name" to "Elvis Presley",
    "furtherDetails" to JsonBuilder(
            "GreatestHits" to arrayOf("Surrender", "Jailhouse rock"),
            "Genre" to "Rock",
            "Died" to 1977)
).toString()
```

Comment: This solution is also not valid. It's showing how to build a JSONObject field by field.