# Using JSONObject in Kotlin always throws an error

Tags: android, kotlin

I know that this question is asked hundreds of time, I've checked more than 30 answer and none worked for me.

I'm running a unit test in android studio using Kotlin. I'm trying to build a `JSONObject` using a `String`.

The method I'm using to build a simple json object is always throwing `Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()`.

**The string I'm using definitely have a valid Json format**.

Is this a bug in android or what??

Here's the method I'm using:

```
fun createTaskJson(): JSONObject {
    val jsonString =
        "{\"id\":138,\"title\":\"G0102-025\",\"type\":\"New Land Evaluation\",\"taskCreationDate\":\"28/01/2020\",\"taskDeliveryDate\":\"02/02/2020\",\"taskCreationTime\":\"05:15 AM\"}"
    val realJson = JSONObject(jsonString)
    return realJson
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Please note that also creating an empty `JSONObject` will throw the same error !!

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

After checking the stacktrace, I've found the following error:

`Method toString in org.json.JSONObject not mocked.`

I've googled it and the solution was to add the following configuration into my `build.gradle` file:

```
    testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

But adding this made the returned `JSONObject` null instead of throwing an exception, even though my string is formatted correctly.

Comment: What about this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295665/how-to-create-a-jsonobject-from-string-in-kotlin/44297201

Comment: Your code works fine for me as it is, so I don't see any issue in the string. How about just try out `Gson` to see if there is an error there too. It also works fine when I do: `Gson().fromJson("your string", HashMap::class.java)`

Comment: @VarunRaj yes I've checked it and it didn't work for me

Comment: I think you should use https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283450/7436566 this way to create a JSON object as you already know the JSON keys.

Comment: @omz1990 yes the Gson method you've mentioned worked. And returned a hash map with the value inside of it. But if you said that no problem happened with the same code at your machine, then there's something wrong with my project/configuration or something like that

Comment: @VarunRaj I've also tried it, I don't know why but creating an Empty `JSONObject` threw the same error!!

Comment: Can you show full java stacktrace of error? Or is it compiler error?

Comment: How can it throw the same error? The error you are getting is `Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()` and there is no `toString()` involved in that answer.

Comment: Are you using some custom font in your IDE? I know something similar has happened to a colleague of mine (not in this context), but had to do with having a string in a file with a custom font. Also have seen issues with copy pasting some illegal characters. But yes, you’re right, there must be some difference as it ran on my machine

Comment: @VarunRaj see the update, it deos!

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish hmm very strange.

Comment: @xinaiz I've checked the full stack trace the error provided was `Method toString in org.json.JSONObject not mocked.` I've added an Update after googling this error. Please check it out

Comment: Yes, check the update. it's now returning null instead of throwing an execption. Even though my json string is correct

Comment: The `toString` method in `JSONObject` is defined as `try { return this.toString(0); } catch (Exception e) { return null; }`. Please put breakpoint at the `return null` statement and check what exception cased it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the updates mentioned in the question above. And after lots of searching. I found out the following:

The solution was in adding the following line into `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'
```

I don't know why, but it's like android have an object with names `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` but when adding the `implementation` to the `build.gradle`file. It handles `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` in another way.

Because after adding the statement to the gradle file, the following warning will be giving by android:

**`json` define classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android**