# Can Kotlin or Swift parse JSON just like Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, swift, kotlin

If I'm using javascript (or TypeScript), I can do following (just idea);

```
object = JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

And I can just use it like this,

```
alert(object.property);
```

Super Simple.

If I'm using Java, I need to create classes and parse it to use it. I understand.

How about Kotlin and Swift. They have optional types, so why single line, Javascript-like simple parsing doesn't exist for them, or does it? (Without even data class or going through JSON's properties)

Comment: [yes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) for swift but for Kotlin you'll need to use something like [Klaxon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin). If you are asking about native support without the use of a class, probably not.

Comment: @aug: Your first link is only for Kotlin transpiled to Javascript.

Comment: @SLaks my bad updated my comment

Comment: Kotlin does not have optional types; Kotlin has type inference. You still need to declare all the classes that you use in Kotlin code.

Comment: What is `Any` then? @yole

Comment: `Any` is Kotlin's equivalent to `java.lang.Object`: http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you look up what JSON stands for it's no wonder why JavaScript has "native support" for it: [**JavaScript Object Notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

In Kotlin you'll need to use libraries for parsing JSON, I'd recommend [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) for that, a library widely used with Java already.