# Android populate arrayOf with firebase data rather than strings

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, spinner

I am new to firebase, so some things are still a bit confusing to me.

I have an array: `var spinnerArray = arrayOf("Dumbell", "Punching Bag", "Yoga Ball", "Skipping Rope")`
which I then pass to a spinner. All that is working. Although, now I want to take it to the next level, which is instead of populating the spinner with the strings I added to the array, I want it to pass the data I have on my firebase database. Reason is, some items have subitems, so I need to use objects instead.

I really don't know how to go around and replace this.
Could you please help me

I have already my app connected to the realtime database.

Thanks

---

```
  {
  "KitList" : {
    "kettle" : {
      "10KG" : "10KG",
      "5KG" : "5KG"
    },
    "punchBag" : "punch bag",
    "sandbag" : "sandbag"
  }
}
```

Someone told me I shouldn't have the value equal to the key?

---

This is my model

```
class KitList(val title: String) {

override fun toString(): String {
    return super.toString()
}}
```

---

This is the activity where the spinner is:

```
class NewKitListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
var myRef = database.getReference("KitList")



var spinnerArray = arrayOf("Dumbell", "Punching Bag", "Yoga Ball", "Skipping Rope")

inner class Item {
    var IdItem: Int = 0
    var Item: String? = null
    var SubItems: ArrayList<Item>? = null
}

var newKitList = mutableListOf<String>()
val selectedItems: MutableList<String>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_kit_list)
    var context = this;
    var addButton = addKitItemBtn

    val spinner = newKitItemSpinner
    val spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray)
    //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    spinner.adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter

    val kitList = newKistListView
    val listViewAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newKitList)
    kitList.adapter = listViewAdapter

    addButton.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val selectedItem = spinner.selectedItem.toString()
            newKitList.add(selectedItem)
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })}}
```

Comment: just create a model so that data in your database can be handled. You can show some sample data with subitems and I can show you how.

Comment: updated post with the data. Someone told me I shouldn't have the value equal to the key?

Comment: Nothing in your code reads anything from the database yet. While I understand you're having a hard time writing the complete code, it's much easier to help if you show us how far you got. That way we can complete it and explain what you missed or where you made a mistake, instead of just providing the code as we would implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have completely removed my answer yesterday and change it with this one**

I have found this library from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41929124/4967534)

this should be the best way for parsing json in kotlin now.

you can find all the answer on the link but here are some basic steps:

1. **Install**

   ```
   repositories {
   jcenter()
   }

   dependencies {
   compile 'com.beust:klaxon:0.30'
   }
   ```
2. Let's say you have this json:

   ```
   [
   {
       "name" : "John",
       "age" : 20
   },
   {
       "name" : "Amy",
       "age" : 25
   },
   {
       "name" : "Jessica",
       "age" : 38
   }
   ]
   ```

We can easily collect all the ages as follows:

```
val array = parse("/e.json") as JsonArray<JsonObject>

val ages = array.long("age")
println("Ages: $ages")

// Prints: Ages: JsonArray(value=[20, 25, 38])
```

Comment: any chance on how I do it in Kotlin? This is my model: 

class KitList(val title: String) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return super.toString()
    }
}

Also, then I do I pass it?

Comment: If you will post a code, not on comment. Edit your question and add the code. So that I can edit my answer as well

Comment: By the way, if you will use data with sub items use drop down menu not spinner

Comment: Got it... The logic for a dropdown is the same yeah? :)

Comment: Yes, and if i am helpful you can mark my answer as correct. Don’t if otherwise

Comment: Any chance to show me an example with what I've got? :)

Comment: I can, but not today. I’m on my way home. I can get back on you tommorow if you want.

Comment: Much appreciated! I will wait.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Overnito, awesome thanks a lot. What about with Firebase? Which is what I intend to use in the future :)

Comment: I can also help you with that. For now close this question by accepting my answer.

Comment: cool. Should I open another question for that, or here is ok?

Comment: You should open another question.

Comment: gonna open it now. EDIT: can't. Need to wait 1 day :/

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options:

1. Implement a [SpinnerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) so you can pass your Firebase Objects and use that instead of an ArrayAdapter.
2. Convert your Firebase Objects to Strings and pass these to the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: You need to subclass SpinnerAdapter so it can take your objects.