# JSON Parsing Takes 30 Seconds

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have a json file, it's about 1 MB. I'm trying to parse this JSON with Klaxon library but it takes about 30 seconds. I don't want to use SQLite. What can i do?

Comment: Maybe try GSON? or Jackson?

Comment: @Peterdk How effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 MB for a JSON file is pretty massive.

> What can i do?

You can:

1. Make your JSON smaller.
2. Try a different parser library and see if it helps.
3. Accept the slow parse time (add a spinner or something).

Comment: Yeah, this isn't very big. I think my JSON parser is bad. I'll try another JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50468095/10381014
Now, my json parse process takes only 1 second.