# How to import standard JSON parsing library in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlin-js

I want to use [kotlin.js parse](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-j-s-o-n/parse.html), but I don't know how to import it.

I tried

*`import org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.parser.sourcemaps.*;`*

but it didn't include JSON parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kotlin.js` is designed for JavaScript platform. But you show Java-styled import in your code. You can't use JavaScript library in Java project. If you have Java project you should find another lib for JSON parsing, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin) can be helpful.

If you want to create Kotlin/JavaScript library [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/create-library-js.html) and [this](https://proandroiddev.com/call-a-javascript-library-from-kotlin-code-as-a-static-type-c2d3755bf79d) links can help you.