# How to read this JSON in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

Now I can read this JSON data like this

```
[{"name":"sidoel"},{"name":"jakabaring"}]
```

With this in `kotlin`

```
recyclerAdapter.setMovieListItems(response.body()!!)
```

How I can read JSON data when structure like this

```
{"data":[{"name":"sidoel"},{"name":"jakabaring"}]}
```

Comment: Check this [How to parse JSON in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin)

Comment: okey thanks all, i need to learn about map with lib gson-converter