# How to parse such a type of JSON?

Tags: kotlin

{
    "data": {
        "id": 204,
        "username": "R_SHAKTISINH",
        "email": "",
        "mobile_no": "9924141516",
        "fullName": "SHAKTISINH",
        "middleName": null,
        "lastName": "RANA",
        "gender": "male",
        "birthday": "07/11/2019",
        "address": "Rajkot",
        "profileImage": "uploads/profile/user.png",
        "child": [
            {
                "id": 138,
                "studentRollId": "",
                "admission_number": "40",
                "account_active": 1,
                "fullName": "Rana Rajnandnibaa Shaktisinh",
                "username": "r_rajnandnibaa",
                "email": "",
                "isLeaderBoard": "",
                "mobile": "F: 9913362628 M: 99241 41516 ",
                "studentClass": "Kindergarten-1",
                "studentSection": "Kindergarten-1",
                "student_image": "uploads/profile/user.png"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Success"
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create this class:

```
    data class DataModel (
    val data: Data,
    val status: Long,
    val message: String
)

data class Data (
    val id: Long,
    val username: String,
    val email: String,
    val mobileNo: String,
    val fullName: String,
    val middleName: Any? = null,
    val lastName: String,
    val gender: String,
    val birthday: String,
    val address: String,
    val profileImage: String,
    val child: List<Child>
)

data class Child (
    val id: Long,
    val studentRollID: String,
    val admissionNumber: String,
    val accountActive: Long,
    val fullName: String,
    val username: String,
    val email: String,
    val isLeaderBoard: String,
    val mobile: String,
    val studentClass: String,
    val studentSection: String,
    val studentImage: String
)
```

now you. can use Gson to parse it.

https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-parse-json-with-gson/