# Getting a specific JSONObject with kotlin in a clean way

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Is there a cleaner way to get the value? I'm not a Kotlin expert and i can't seem to find alot on this online

```
var options = request.getJSONObject("optionsObject");
var readingPosition = options.getJSONObject("readingPosition");
var selector = readingPosition.getJSONObject("selector");
var value = selector.getString("value");
```

the json:

```
{
   "optionsObject":{
      "readingPosition":{
         "format":"application\/epub+zip",
         "selector":{
            "type":"FragmentSelector",
            "conformsTo":"http:\/\/www.idpf.org\/epub\/linking\/cfi\/epub-cfi.html",
            "value":"epubcfi(\/6\/2!\/0)"
         }
      },
      "readingProgress":0
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using retrofit just make a class

```
data class youcalssname(
 val yourJsonobjet:YourJsonobjectType,
 //like this
 val value:String,
 )
```

and get the data easily  **yourclassname.value**  for more check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin)

Comment: idk feels like overkill to me

Comment: for this kind of json response i think your code is  clean and less complex.

Comment: i agree, but it still suprises me that there's not a more efficient way

Comment: if you are getting this type of response in lots of api than you can create a pojo class or model and get and set the data into model class and get it but if its seem you getting only one time response thats okay its clean and less complex

Comment: if you get the response one time its okay but if you get same response in different api and in different activity and fragment  you have to write all you code agagin to get the data but if you use model you have just pass the model and get responce into model and no need to call request.getJSONObject("optionsObject"); . and you can simple pass the model from one activity to another whole data it reduce code complex and if from server the api responce object change you have to change every where but if you use model you just need to change only in model .