# I want to fetch the value of boolean "status" of the json data and perform some operation based on that value in kotlin

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin, android-developer-api

I am a beginner in android development. I want to fetch the value of a boolean  "status" of the json data and perform some operation based on that value in kotlin.

This is my json data.

```json
{
    "status": true,
    "message": Hello Good Morning!",
    "data": {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "updateNeeded": true,
        "organizationId": "1",
        "displayName": "ABC DEF",
        "established": "1990-01-01",
        "created": "2020-03-10"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin

Comment: What is the issue then? Where you stuck in this?

Comment: I dont know how to do it. @PriyankaRajput

Comment: Share your code , If you have any.

Comment: You just need to get the key and its value from the response. It is easy. Just share your code what you are doing in your file.

Comment: I dont have code . I dont know how to do it. @PriyankaRajput

Comment: Ok, Tell me , form where you are getting above response?

Comment: This is my code @PriyankaRajput   val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("http://date.jsontest.com/")
            .build()
        var gson = Gson()
        var mMineUserEntity = gson?.fromJson(request, MyUserEntity.MineUserInfo::class.java)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223006/discussion-between-yogesh-kumar-and-priyanka-rajput).