# How do I get the text from an URL in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I tried to use this function:

```
URL("url").readText()
```

for example with the URL http://date.jsontest.com/ to get a JSON string and manipulate it. However it just doesn't work, it crash.

I mean how to have the text of what is display using kotlin on android ?

Ok I find a way

```
    val url: URL? = try {
    URL("https://www.instagram.com/p/CNVUZyrDVSQ/?__a=1")
    }catch (e: MalformedURLException){
    Log.d("Exception", e.toString())
    null
    }
```

and

```
fun URL.getString(): String? {
    val stream = openStream()
    return try {
        val r = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream))
        val result = StringBuilder()
        var line: String?
        while (r.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
            result.append(line).appendLine()
        }
        result.toString()
    }catch (e: IOException){
        e.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin)

Comment: @YassinHajaj I think they're actually asking how to read the file in the first place, not how to parse it.

Comment: @HenryTwist URL readText returns a String so its already there

Comment: Yes I know, I presumed they were having an issue with it as opposed to not knowing how to parse it. But we will see!

Comment: @HenryTwist yes I have an issue it make crash my app

Comment: You need to use some HTTP client for this

Comment: If you're trying to diagnose a crash then you need to [edit] your question and post the stack trace. Trying to guess isn't very efficient.

Comment: @HenryTwist I know it from URL().readtext so I do not need to diagnose it

Comment: Well then I'm not sure what your question is for if it's already diagnosed, good luck!

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty similar:

```kotlin
val htmlString = File("/path/to/sample.html").readText()
```

Comment: it doesn't help me because I want from an url not an file but thanks

Comment: @RiyadCornu then you should fix the title of the Question. For now it sounds like you want to read a file