# how to parse this type of json Response in android using kotlin

Tags: kotlin

{
"ART01": {
"outletType": "single",
"outletDetails": [
{
"outletName": "ARTISANAL BAKEHOUSE",
"serverIP": "150.129.182.214:81",
"outletKey": "DESKTOP-N8Q4C2M"
}
]
},
"BHW01": {
"outletType": "single",
"outletDetails": [
{
"outletName": "Bhawan",
"serverIP": "43.228.143.194:81",
"outletKey": "E1"
}
]
}
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin)

Comment: yes,when we convert json response to kotlin class its to big,and also fix statically

Comment: Any idea to get in key value pair in kotlin

Comment: @Nitishtiwary please explain which part exactly you're struggling with. Key-value pairs in Kotlin are usually expressed as `Map<K, V>`. The best to get help would be if you could share the (maybe incomplete) Kotlin model you designed to deserialize this payload, and point out the parts where you don't know what to do.

Comment: { "ART01": { "outletType": "single", "outletDetails": [ { "outletName": "ARTISANAL BAKEHOUSE", "serverIP": "150.129.182.214:81", "outletKey": "DESKTOP-N8Q4C2M" } ] }, "BHW01": { "outletType": "single", "outletDetails": [ { "outletName": "Bhawan", "serverIP": "43.228.143.194:81", "outletKey": "E1" } ] } } .this json format not fix its increase and decrese also ,then which type of model class create for this type of json response

Comment: the value of json also increses at run time or decreases