# How I convert string response into Array List

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, okhttp

I'm using websockets, and in the `onMessage()` method, I'm receiving a response in string form. I want to store this response in model class. How I convert this string response into array list?

```
[{"sender_id":"0008","created_at":"1313211849934","receiver_id":"0003","message":"second message","id":1,"chat_id":50,"type":"text"},{"sender_id":"0008","created_at":"1519211809934","receiver_id":"0003","message":"second message","id":2,"chat_id":50,"type":"text"}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```kotlin
class Data {
  var sender_id:String? = null
  var created_at:String? = null
  var receiver_id:String? = null
  var message:String? = null
  var id:Int
  var chat_id:Long
  var type:String? = null
}

val jsonContent = "[{"sender_id":"0008","created_at":"1313211849934","receiver_id":"0003","message":"second message","id":1,"chat_id":50,"type":"text"},{"sender_id":"0008","created_at":"1519211809934","receiver_id":"0003","message":"second message","id":2,"chat_id":50,"type":"text"}]"
val data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonContent, Data:class.java)
```