# parse string to an array in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can I convert a string to an array of strings in Kotlin? To demonstrate, I have this:

```
val input_string = "[Hello, World]"
```

I would like to convert it to `["Hello", "World"]`.

Comment: How about [parsing it as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the array elements do not contain commas, you can do:

```
someString.removeSurrounding("[", "]")
    .takeIf(String::isNotEmpty) // this handles the case of "[]"
    ?.split(", ") 
    ?: emptyList() // in the case of "[]"
```

This will give you a `List<String>`. If you want an `Array<String>`:

```
someString.removeSurrounding("[", "]")
    .takeIf(String::isNotEmpty)
    ?.split(", ")
    ?.toTypedArray()
    ?: emptyArray()
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the step with _takeIf_ (and _?: emptyList()_)?

Comment: @lukas.j Yes. For the input string `[]`, you want an empty list/array, not a list with one empty string in it, right?

Comment: Of course, you're right (almost every time I come back to Kotlin I stumble across the _split_ specialities...).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the strings only consist of letters and/or numbers you could also do it like this

```
val input_string = "[Hello, World]"
val list = Regex("\\w+").findAll(input_string).toList().map { it.value }
```