How to read and decode a remote JSON data in Jetpack Compose app?
By placing the JSON file locally in src/main/assets folder you can easily access its content to deserialize it (I used .decodeFromString() method here). However, it's not clear how to deserialize a remote JSON data in Jetpack Compose app.
For example, a data located at the address https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats or at the address https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all.
Here's a code with a local JSON parsing:
@Serializable
data class Root(val tenants: List<Tenant>)

@Serializable
data class Tenant(val name: String, val room: Int)

@Composable
fun DecodedText() {
    var text: String by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        val json = readJsonFromAssets(context = context, fileName = "sample.json")
        val decoded = Json.decodeFromString<Root>(json).tenants

        for (i in decoded.indices) {
            text += decoded[i].name + " – "
            text += decoded[i].room.toString() + "\n"
        }
    }
    Text(
        text = text,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Black,
        fontSize = 22.sp,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(50.dp)
    )
}
fun readJsonFromAssets(context: Context, fileName: String): String {
    return context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
}

I'd like to know how to do this using the kotlin serialization plugin. Any help appreciated.

It's good to know Jetpack Compose is a UI framework and not meant for this kind of logic, generally this logic lives inside of a https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel. There I would look into just parsing JSON with kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin



You are not getting a file from that url you are getting json data there is a difference.


You need to pick a networking framework that you are going to be using because each has their own way of parsing json data into objects. The most common/popular one for Android is probably Retrofit but there are others available.



After carefully studying this issue, I came to the following solution. I tried to parse JSON data using both web addresses, both examples are decoded fine, for my answer I've chosen the second address. Here's my code:
typealias Countries = List<Country>

private val jsonPty = Json {
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
}
@Serializable
data class Country(
    val name: Names
)
@Serializable
data class Names(
    val common: String,
    val official: String
)


@ExperimentalSerializationApi
@Composable
fun RemoteDecodedText() {
    val url = URL("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
    var json: String by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var parsedJson: String by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        scope.launch {
            json = url.openStream().use {
                it.readAllBytes().decodeToString()
            }
            parsedJson = jsonPty.decodeFromString<Countries>(json)[64].name.official
        }
    }
    Text(
        text = "Location: $parsedJson",
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Black,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(60.dp)
    )
}

Result (index=64) :
// Location: Kingdom of Morocco

